Bioliogiaj ordoj: adjektivoj aŭ nomoj?
Saluton. En la PIV, la biologiaj ordoj finiĝas kun -a (ekz. pleŭronektoformaj, gruformaj, ktp). La sufikso -a estas sufikso por adjektivoj. Sed la donita difino de la PIV similas difinon de nomoj (Ordo de …). Mi serĉis se ekzistus sufikson -forma (kiel -ed- por la biologiaj familioj), sed mi trovis nenion. Mia demando estas stranga, ĉar mi scias, ke se iu finigas kun -a, tio estas adjektivo, sed, ĉu la ordoj estas nomoj aŭ adjektivoj? Kial la ordoj finiĝas kun -formaj, kaj ne kun -formoj?
Tria kaj plej malgrava demando estas kiel nomi ulojn de la ordoj. Ĉu estas -ulo aŭ -ano? Ekzemple, ĉu estas “gruformano” aŭ “gruformulo”?
Dankon.

La sufikso -forma estas la vorto formo kun la -a suffikso, same kiel en la (pseŭdo)latinaj nomoj de la ordoj?

Por uloj oni uzu -ul-.

Nomoj de ordoj ne estas regulaj en la formo internacia. Dum por plantoj, algoj kaj fungoj oni regule uzas -ales, kaj por birdoj oni regule uzas -iformes, por mamuloj kaj senvertebruloj nomado ne estas tiel normigita.
Se la nomo de ordo ne estas analizebla en la esperanta oni povas ĝin konsideri substantiva. Ekzemple himenopter aŭ neŭroptero.
Se la nomo de ordo estas almenaŭ parte analizebla en la esperanta la finan formon decidos la tipo de la radiko/kunmetaĵo:

gruform- iĝas nature adjektiva (ovoforma, belforma, longforma...) kaj almetas -(a)j aŭ -ulo(j). Io simila okazas kun ĉiuj X-formaj bestoj. Do: gruformaj, pleŭronektoformaj. Kial ne gruformuloj? Oni povus diri tion, sed la -aj formo venkis. Kial? Eble pro tio ke ĝi aspektas pli intime ligita al la latina originala formo, aŭ pro la ŝajnkunmetaĵo (oni povus legi gru-formuloj), aŭ pro historiaj kialoj... Gramatike gruformuloj eblas, sed oni devis elekti unu el eblaj formoj.

rostr- estas substantiva kaj devige rekte almetos -ulo(j) (elefantoj estas rostruloj).

karnomanĝ- estas transitive verba kaj almetas -ulo(j), do la ordo estas karnomanĝuloj/karnovoruloj. Estis aliaj ebloj, kiel -ant ekzemple (jam en la Fundamenta Krestomatio aperas viandomanĝanto kaj fruktomanĝanto en teksto vi vegetarismo).


Tio ne estas tuta listo de ebloj. Nur ebla parta klarigo por nomoj de ordo (tio iĝas pli malbone en aliaj partoj de la hierarĥio).
